# Blocking Upload button on a modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, user-controls

I have no access to SPFX, or any dev tasks , else this would be breeze. Has anyone at all successfully blocked the upload button and new button (not to be even seen) and allow a user to edit the document, rename the document and delete the document ? It would be miracle if anyone has successfully done this - I am banging my head with Sharepoint permissions and I cannot seem to be able rename without the Add document permission. And the add document permissions allows use of upload... any ideas what so ever ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are right. You will have to give up the ability to rename items if you wish to block Add item.

Comment: yes I have sorted it, but we cannot rename but we can do delete, and no add a nd no upload / new buttons. Just use contribute access and replicate it and remove the add tick.

Comment: Makes sense as a rename is an Add and Delete behind the covers